# Existem patterns compartilhados entre paradigma funcional e orientado a objetos?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, programação-funcional

Desing patterns é um assunto que tem forte apelo a orientação a objetos. Dificilmente conseguimos ver na literatura esses assuntos associados a outro paradigma. No entanto, na versão 16.8 do React surgiram os Hooks, que permitiam usar recursos do React sem usar classes, trazendo maior apelo da biblioteca para o paradigma funcional. Já haviam críticas ao modo de usar classes no React, mas queria ater ao assunto dos patterns. A maior dúvida é essa: O conhecimento normal dos padrões de projetos podem ser reaproveitados em um paradigma funcional em algum nível? Paradigma novo, boas práticas novas?
É possível reaproveitar o conhecimento do design patterns em programação funciona?

Comment: Acredito que refinar o texto, remover as tags [tag:javascript] e [tag:react] e adicionar a tag [tag:engenharia-de-software] agregue mais valor a sua pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado. Vou alterar!